Wrong Colors Xiaomi
Colors are not show as they should be, only with Xiaomi. This is part of my code:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO);

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="MeuTema" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/encarnado</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/verde</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>

but this peace of code do not show correct colors as it should
        holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.valueTextView.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        if (valorAtual > valorSalvo) {
            holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.valueTextView.getContext(), R.color.verde));
        } else if (valorAtual < valorSalvo) {
            holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.valueTextView.getContext(), R.color.encarnado));
        }

This only happens with Xiaomi, not Samsung, nor emulators.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite React?PHP?JavaScript?forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags. Also adding a (few) screenshot(s) of the colours would help us visualise the problem.

This is because Xiaomi does not use standard Android OS.

And how to solve ir?
